# perform BeautifulSoup operation on list of lists while maintaining structure in python

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

I have a list of beautiful soup object that i am trying to further parse for contents of  cells. My output becomes a list of lists with 3 items on each since the table had 3 columns.

```html
file = <html><p><center><h1>  Interference Report  </h1></center><p>
<b>  Interference Report Project File:  </b>C:\Users\ksobon\Documents\test_project_03_ksobon.rvt  <br>  <b>  Created:  </b>  Monday, May 26, 2014 7:52:32 PM  <br>  <b>  Last Update:  </b>    <br>
 <p><table border=on>  <tr>  <td></td>  <td ALIGN="center">A</td>  <td  ALIGN="center">B</td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  1  </td>  <td>  Workset1 : Walls : Basic Wall : E103-CON 100mm : id 469021     </td>  <td>  Workset1 : Furniture : FUR_BoardroomTable10Chairs_gm : Board Room Layout : id   482259  </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  2  </td>  <td>  Workset1 : Walls : Basic Wall : E103-CON 100mm : id 469021    </td>  <td>  Workset1 : Walls : Basic Wall : E103-CON 100mm : id 483442  </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  3  </td>  <td>  Workset1 : Walls : Basic Wall : E103-CON 100mm : id 469060    </td>  <td>  Workset1 : Furniture : FUR_Sofa_gm : 2100mm : id 475041  </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  4  </td>  <td>  Workset1 : Walls : Basic Wall : E103-CON 100mm : id 469109   </td>  <td>  Workset1 : Furniture : FUR_Sofa_gm : 2100mm : id 475273  </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  5  </td>  <td>  Workset1 : Walls : Basic Wall : E103-CON 100mm : id 469178   </td>  <td>  Workset1 : Furniture : FUR_Sofa_gm : 2100mm : id 475510  </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  6  </td>  <td>  Workset1 : Walls : Basic Wall : E103-CON 100mm : id 469178    </td>  <td>  Workset1 : Furniture : FUR_Sofa_gm : 2100mm : id 482306  </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  7  </td>  <td>  whatever : Doors : DOR_Single_gm : 800w, 2100h (720Leaf) -  Mark 102B : id 472052  </td>  <td>  Workset1 : Windows : WIN-ConceptWindowFixed_gm : 1200 H   x 1200 W - Mark 102B : id 472822  </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  8  </td>  <td>  whatever : Doors : DOR_Single_gm : 800w, 2100h (720Leaf) -  Mark 101A : id 472376  </td>  <td>  Workset1 : Windows : WIN-ConceptWindowFixed_gm : 1200 H   x 1200 W - Mark 101C : id 472720  </td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>  9  </td>  <td>  Workset1 : Windows : WIN-ConceptWindowFixed_gm : 1800 H x  1200 W 2 - Mark 101B : id 472688  </td>  <td>  Workset1 : Furniture : FUR_Sofa_gm : 2100mm   : id 482306  </td>  </tr>
</table>
<p><b>  End of Interference Report  </b>
</html>
```

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(file)
    tag = soup.findAll('tr')

```
for i in tag:
    txt.append(i.findAll('td'))
```

Now i want to convert each sublist element to text so i tried:
    txt1 = [i.text for x in txt for i in x]
My output for txt1 however comes out as a flat list instead of list of lists. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Put `i.text` in a list:

```
txt1 = [[i.text] for x in txt for i in x]
```

You are flattening the list with your list comprehension extracting all the elements into one list.

```
l = [[1,2],[2,3],[5,6]]

flatten_l = [x for y in l for x in y]
print (flatten_l)
[1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```

Maybe you need map:

```
l=[[1,2,4],[2,3,5],[5,6,7]]

print [map(str, s) for s in l]

[['1', '2', '4'], ['2', '3', '5'], ['5', '6', '7']]
```

Using your code this calls i.text on each element maintaining the structure.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(file)

tag = soup.findAll('tr')
txt=[(i.findAll('td')) for i in tag]
final=[[] for x in range(len(txt))]
for j,k in enumerate(txt):
    for i in k:
        final[j].append(i.text)  

 print final
 [[u'', u'A', u'B'], [u'1', u'Workset1 : Walls : Basic Wall : E103-CON 100mm : id 469021', u'Workset1 : Furniture : FUR_BoardroomTable10Chairs_gm : Board Room Layout......
```

Comment: well the result of txt is a list of lists that contains 3 items each since there are 3 columns in each table. i want to maintain that structure but convert each object to a string. your suggestion to put i.text into brackets gives me a separate list for each item. so i guess i need to ask how do i iterate over a lists of lists without changing its original structure.

Comment: map function it is. I need to remember that it does that. Thanks!

Comment: one more thing though. I really wanted to use function text that comes from beautifulsoup module and you suggested str. when i sub str for text it throws up an error that text is not defined. ideas?

Comment: try using loops instead of list comp and call the method on each element to update them you can use something like map(i.text,j)

Comment: for i in txt:
 txt1.append(map(i.text, txt)) this still doesnt work.

Comment: you have ten lists in you txt file, I will add code that will add the text to a sublist corresponding to the index of each sublist to a new list.